# Swift textview growing direction

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

so i have a textview inside a uiview. And my question is how to make my textivew grow in up direction when textview goes to the next line as well as my uiview.

```
var textheightcontraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
var viewheightconstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!


func setup4(){
    view.addSubview(colorview)
    colorview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customtableview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    colorview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    colorview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    viewheightconstraint = colorview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
    viewheightconstraint.isActive = true
    colorview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    colorview.addSubview(customtextview2)
    customtextview2.backgroundColor = .white
    customtextview2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorview.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    customtextview2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorview.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    customtextview2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    textheightcontraint = customtextview2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 39)
    textheightcontraint.isActive = true
    customtextview2.delegate = self

}
func setuptextview(){
    let fixedWidth = customtextview2.frame.size.width
    let newSize = customtextview2.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    self.textheightcontraint.constant = newSize.height
    self.viewheightconstraint.constant = newSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    setuptextview()
}
```

Comment: You should make an attempt to solve the problem and show what you have done so far to solve the problem if you expect the SO community to help you.

Comment: do you know how to do it?

Comment: I want you to learn how to do it. If you hit roadbumps along the way, we can help you.

Comment: so do you know how to do it ?

Comment: what i'm working on right now is to use nslayoutconstraint on the height anchor of the textview

Comment: Yes add your code to the question then. So that we can have a look at what you did to get there.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485269/uitextview-auto-height-up-direction

Comment: That does not involve autolayout. Check my answer, it should work. I don't have my macbook with me or i would have checked and told you myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the text view (and the view it's contained in) to keep its **bottom** at the same position, and expand upward as you type?

To do that, disable scrolling in the text view, and set up your constraints so the **bottom** of the containing view is constrained to a y-position:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/9/18.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var theContainingView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var theTextView: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        theContainingView.backgroundColor = .cyan

        theContainingView.addSubview(theTextView)

        view.addSubview(theContainingView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainingView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            theContainingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theContainingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // Constrain the Bottom of the containing view. As the textView grows (or shrinks) with input,
            // the TOP of the view will move up or down
            theContainingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 300.0),

            ])

        theTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        theTextView.text = "This is the starting text."

    }

}
```

Results:

[image]